# Как определять сложность у рекурсивных алгоритмов?

Tags: c++, алгоритм, рекурсия, сложность

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int no_zeroes(int a, int b) {
    
    if (a > b + 1) {
        return 0;
    }
    if (a == 0 || b == 0) {
        return 1;
    }
    return no_zeroes(a, b - 1) + no_zeroes(a - 1, b - 1);

}
int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");

    int a, b;
    cout << "Введите количество нулей: ";
    cin >> a;
    cout << "Введите количество единиц: ";
    cin >> b;
    cout << "Ответ: " << no_zeroes(a, b);

   
    return 0;
}
```

Каким образом нужно определять сложность у рекурсивных алгоритмов? Что-то подсказывает, что сложность в худшем случае `2^(a + b)`, но как это можно сделать строже?

Comment: `2^(a+b)` - не сложность, `O(2^n)` - вот это сложность. Рекурсия на сложность алгоритма не влияет сама по себе.

Comment: `setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");` вот эта штука совершенно бесполезная. Просто сохраните файл в `UTF-8`. Под виндой для `cmd.exe` можно кодировку так сменить `std::system("chcp 65001")`

Comment: @megorit *Рекурсия на сложность алгоритма не влияет сама по себе* — очень интересное утверждение. Что же тогда такое "алгоритм"? Например, рекурсивное вычисление чисел Фибоначчи "в лоб" — его сложность от рекурсии не зависит? Кстати, насчет `setlocale` тоже вы не совсем правы. В данной программе, если она написана на cp1251, это вполне работает... А вот если сохранить в utf8 и не указать локаль (типа `setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus.utf8");`), получим кракозябры. Смена кодировки — а почему тогда именно utf-8, а не просто 1251? :)

Comment: @Harry, фактически рекурсия - механизм без которого можно обойтись. Стек или очередь состояний и простая итерация вычисляют любую рекурсивную функцию. Сложность при такой трансформации не меняется. Так что да, рекурсия сама по себе на сложность алгоритма не влияет.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy OK, какова сложность вычисления n-го числа Фибоначчи? :) Некорректный вопрос? но ведь рекурсия никак не влияет на сложность...

Comment: @Harry, если при вычислении *F_n* используется только литерал *1* и только операция сложения, то можно показать что сложность равна *2 * F_n - 1*. Делается это независимо от рекурсии.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy Это один алгоритм вычисления. Можно вообще константный, можно логарифмический... А есть алгоритм "в лоб". *Рекурсивный*. И как после этого говорить, что алгоритм не зависит от рекурсии? В общем случае? Впрочем, у меня ощущение какое-то, что мы говорим о разных вещах, какая-то терминологическая нестыковка...

Comment: @Harry, да потому что UTF-8 уже давно стал международным стандартом и нативно поддерживается плюсовыми компиляторами. Т.е. можно переменные на любом языке калякать (но лучше не надо). Я всегда делал только так, а `cmd.exe` - это просто ужас ужасный. Если кто-то действительно хочет научиться программированию, первое что ему нужно сделать - постоавить Linux. Если вы рекурсивно вызываете функцию по одному разу за вызов то это `O(n)`, т.е. просто перебор, только вместо итерации рекурсия. Рекурсия - способ прохода, он напрямую со сложностью не связан, сам вопрос не вполне корректен.

Comment: @megorit Простите уж, но разобраться в потоке слов, не разделенных на ответы по смыслу, я не смог. Возражать вам, особенно после совета ставить Linux, не буду - просто смысла не имеет :) Оставайтесь по всем вопросам со своим мнением...

Answer (score 6):

1. Выписать функцию сложности в виде рекуррентного соотношения.
2. - (а) Прочитать [Конкретную математику](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0) Кнута, Грехэма, Поташника, научиться работать с производящими функциями, вывести формулу для функции сложности ...
   - (б) ... или понять что решение связано с биномиальными коэффициентами. А для них решения выводятся из линейности - не надо читать толстые книги.
3. Доказать что найденная функция отвечает всем требованиям из первого пункта.

***NB** В этом ответе выведена точная формула для времени работы. Этого обычно не нужно (*О-большое*), но тут повезло.*

***NB** Универсального способа оценить сложность любого алгоритма не существует. Потому что тогда появится решение для [проблемы остановки](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0_%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B8), а этого не может быть никогда. Оценка сложности всегда будет сложной. :)*

### Обозначения (первый пункт программы)

Обозначим *f(a, b)* - время вычисления `no_zeroes(a, b)`. Тогда *f* обладает следующими свойствами:

- *f(a, b) = 1* если *a > b + 1* (первое условие);
- *f(a, b) = 1* если *a = 0* или *b = 0* (второе условие);
- *f(a, b) = 1 + f(a, b - 1) + f(a - 1, b - 1)* (рекурсивная ветка).

Не запутайтесь: *f* похожа по свойствам на `no_zeros` но они не равны. Тело `no_zeros` исполняется за константу, если исключить рекурсивные вызовы. Эта константа в формулах выше замена на единицу - *O-большое* разрешает. Иначе говоря *f(a, b)* - число рекурсивных вызовов `no_zeroes` если та вызвана с аргументами *a, b*.

Введём обозначение *(<sup>b</sup><sub>a</sub>)* - [биномиальный коэффициент](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%8D%D1%84%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82).

### Формула (последний пункт программы)

Утверждение: если *0 ≤ a ≤ b + 2*, то *f(a, b) = 2[(<sup>b</sup><sub>a</sub>) + (<sup>b</sup><sub>a-1</sub>) + (<sup>b</sup><sub>a-2</sub>)] - 1*.

Доказательство:

- Первое условие для *f* упрощается до *a = b + 2*. Тогда

  *f(a, b) = f(b + 2, b) = 2[(<sup>b</sup><sub>b+2</sub>) + (<sup>b</sup><sub>b+1</sub>) + (<sup>b</sup><sub>b</sub>)] - 1 = 2[0 + 0 + 1] - 1 = 1*
- Второе условие, часть *a = 0*. Тогда

  *f(a, b) = f(0, b) = 2[(<sup>b</sup><sub>0</sub>) + (<sup>b</sup><sub>-1</sub>) + (<sup>b</sup><sub>-2</sub>)] - 1 = 2[1 + 0 + 0] - 1 = 1*
- Второе условие, часть *b = 0* превращается в *b = 0* и *0 ≤ a ≤ 2*. Тогда одно из слагаемых в квадратных скобках - единица, остальные два - нули:

  *f(a, b) = f(a, 0) = 2[(<sup>0</sup><sub>a</sub>) + (<sup>0</sup><sub>a-1</sub>) + (<sup>0</sup><sub>a-2</sub>)] - 1 = 2[1] - 1 = 1*
- Рекурсивная ветка: *b > 0*, *0 < a ≤ b + 1*. Тогда

  *f(a, b) = 2[(<sup>b</sup><sub>a</sub>) + (<sup>b</sup><sub>a-1</sub>) + (<sup>b</sup><sub>a-2</sub>)] - 1 =*

  *= 2[((<sup>b-1</sup><sub>a</sub>)+(<sup>b-1</sup><sub>a-1</sub>)) + ((<sup>b-1</sup><sub>a-1</sub>)+(<sup>b-1</sup><sub>a-2</sub>)) + ((<sup>b-1</sup><sub>a-2</sub>)+(<sup>b-1</sup><sub>a-3</sub>))] - 1 =*

  *= 2[(<sup>b-1</sup><sub>a</sub>) + (<sup>b-1</sup><sub>a-1</sub>) + (<sup>b-1</sup><sub>a-2</sub>)] + 2[(<sup>b-1</sup><sub>a-1</sub>) + (<sup>b-1</sup><sub>a-2</sub>) + (<sup>b-1</sup><sub>a-3</sub>)] - 1 =*

  *= 1 + [2[(<sup>b-1</sup><sub>a</sub>) + (<sup>b-1</sup><sub>a-1</sub>) + (<sup>b-1</sup><sub>a-2</sub>)] - 1] + [2[(<sup>b-1</sup><sub>a-1</sub>) + (<sup>b-1</sup><sub>a-2</sub>) + (<sup>b-1</sup><sub>a-3</sub>)] - 1] =*

  *= 1 + f(a, b - 1) + f(a - 1, b - 1)*

Доказано.

### Выводы

*f(a, b) = 2[(<sup>b</sup><sub>a</sub>) + (<sup>b</sup><sub>a-1</sub>) + (<sup>b</sup><sub>a-2</sub>)] - 1* достигает максимума если *2(a-1) ≈ b*. В [википедии](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%8D%D1%84%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82#%D0%90%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BF%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%B8_%D0%BE%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B8) есть оценки из которых выводится *f(a, b) = O(2<sup>b</sup>/√(πb/2))*.

### Как догадаться до формулы (пункт 2(б))

Рекурсивная часть `no_zeros` повторяет рекуррентную формулу для биномиальных коэффициентов. Сравните:

- `no_zeros(a, b) = no_zeros(a, b - 1) + no_zeros(a - 1, b - 1)`
- *(<sup>b</sup><sub>a</sub>) = (<sup>b-1</sup><sub>a</sub>) + (<sup>b-1</sup><sub>a-1</sub>)*

Это всегда означает что функция вычисляет какую-то линейную комбинацию биномиальных коэффициентов. В нашем случае `no_zeros(a, b)` = *(<sup>b-1</sup><sub>a</sub>)*. Догадаться можно посмотрев таблицу значений `no_zeros`. Каждый кто видел [треугольник Паскаля](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA_%D0%9F%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8F) его уже не забывает никогда:

> ```
> b
>
> 6   1  7 21 35 35 21  7  1  0  ...
> 5   1  6 15 20 15  6  1  0  ...
> 4   1  5 10 10  5  1  0  ...
> 3   1  4  6  4  1  0  ...
> 2   1  3  3  1  0  ...
> 1   1  2  1  0  ...
> 0   1  1  0  ...
>
>     0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  a
> ```

Но это таблица для `no_zeros`, а нам нужна для *f*. У *f* другая рекуррентная формула, другая таблица - там труднее увидеть биномиальные коэффициенты. Поэтому отвлечёмся на минуту.

Давайте на минуту представим что `no_zeros` возвращает не числа, а формулы для их вычисления. Например:

> ```
> no_zeros(2, 2) = no_zeros(1, 2) + no_zeros(1, 1) =
> = (no_zeros(0, 2) + no_zeros(0, 1)) + (no_zeros(0, 1) + no_zeros(0, 0)) =
> = (0 + 1) + (1 + 1) = 0 + 1 + 1 + 1
> ```

Число знаков в последней сумме (пробелы отбрасываем) совпадает со сложностью вычисления `no_zeros`: `0` - первое условие, `1` - второе условие, `+` - рекурсивный вызов.

Следите за руками: если бы в формуле не было нулей, то число плюсов было бы на единицу меньше числа единиц. А число единиц равно результату `no_zeros`. Следовательно, сложность вычисления была бы *(<sup>b-1</sup><sub>a</sub>) + (<sup>b-1</sup><sub>a</sub>) - 1*. Сложность функции пропорциональна значению функции потому что мы складываем единицы!

Нули всё портят. Можно доказать что их доля мала (не велика), но...

Вернёмся к *f(a, b)*. Таблица значений:

> ```
> b
>
> 6   1 13 43 81 99 81 43 13  1  ...
> 5   1 11 31 49 49 31 11  1  ...
> 4   1  9 21 27 21  9  1  ...
> 3   1  7 13 13  7  1  ...
> 2   1  5  7  5  1  ...
> 1   1  3  3  1  ...
> 0   1  1  1  ...
>
>     0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  a
> ```

В каждом ряду центральная симметрия. Значения образуют треугольник обрамлённый единицами. Он похож на треугольник Паскаля.

Из формулы *f(a, b) = 1 + f(a, b - 1) + f(a - 1, b - 1)* уберём единицу заменой *g(a, b) = f(a, b) + 1*:

*(g(a, b) - 1) = 1 + (g(a, b - 1) - 1) + (g(a - 1, b - 1) - 1)*

*g(a, b) = g(a, b - 1) + g(a - 1, b - 1)*

Таблица значений *g(a, b)*:

> ```
> b
>
> 6   2 14 44 82100 82 44 14  2  ...
> 5   2 12 32 50 50 32 12  2  ...
> 4   2 10 22 28 22 10  2  ...
> 3   2  8 14 14  8  2  ...
> 2   2  6  8  6  2  ...
> 1   2  4  4  2  ...
> 0   2  2  2  ...
>
>     0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  a
> ```

Все значения чётные. Делим на два: *h(a, b) = g(a, b) / 2*. Таблица:

> ```
> b
>
> 6   1  7 22 41 50 41 22  7  1  ...
> 5   1  6 16 25 25 16  6  1  ...
> 4   1  5 11 14 11  5  1  ...
> 3   1  4  7  7  4  1  ...
> 2   1  3  4  3  1  ...
> 1   1  2  2  1  ...
> 0   1  1  1  ...
>
>     0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  a
> ```

Последнюю таблицу можно расписать как сумму трёх таблиц:

> ```
> b                                                                                                       
>                                                                                                         
> 6   1  6 15 20 15  6  1  0  ...       0  1  6 15 20 15  6  1  0  ...       0  0  1  6 15 20 15  6  1  0 
> 5   1  5 10 10  5  1  0  ...          0  1  5 10 10  5  1  0  ...          0  0  1  5 10 10  5  1  0  ..
> 4   1  4  6  4  1  0  ...             0  1  4  6  4  1  0  ...             0  0  1  4  6  4  1  0  ...  
> 3   1  3  3  1  0  ...            +   0  1  3  3  1  0  ...            +   0  0  1  3  3  1  0  ...     
> 2   1  2  1  0  ...                   0  1  2  1  0  ...                   0  0  1  2  1  0  ...        
> 1   1  1  0  ...                      0  1  1  0  ...                      0  0  1  1  0  ...           
> 0   1  0 ...                          0  1  0 ...                          0  0  1  0 ...               
>                                                                                                         
>     0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  a      0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  a         0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  a
> ```

Это три треугольника Паскаля: первый нормальный, второй смещён вправо на столбец, третий - на два столбца. Следовательно *h(a, b) = (<sup>b</sup><sub>a</sub>) + (<sup>b</sup><sub>a-1</sub>) + (<sup>b</sup><sub>a-2</sub>)*.

В действительности таблицы рисовать не нужно. Достаточно соотношения для *h* (даже для *g*) и трёх единиц (для *g* двоек) в нулевой строке. Из каждой единицы растёт свой треугольник Паскаля, которые складываются в силу линейности рекуррентной формулы.

Теперь проходим всю цепочку назад, пишем формулу для *f(a, b)*, пишем начальные значения, доказываем, пишем ответ.

Comment: *Тут нет объяснения как догадаться до формулы для f(a, b).* Собственно, все решения рекурсивных уравнений состоят из двух частей: очень сложной, состоящей в том, чтоб догадаться, как выглядит ответ, и очень простой - доказать его матиндукцией...

Comment: @Harry, теперь есть. Вы украли у меня вечер. С вас причитается.

Comment: Да я, собственно, и не настаивал... :) Кстати, забавно, что я в этой рекурсии треугольник Паскаля пе опознал, хотя еще в школе писал даже какую-то работу по его свойствам...

Answer (score 5):

В координатах a-b выполняя дочерний вызов, мы суть сдвигаемся в одном из двух направлений:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Т.е., пренебрегая неоднородностью около начала координат, задача сводится к вычислению числа маршрутов, по которым можно добраться из заданной точки, в точку (a=0, b=-1), двигаясь только по разрешенным направлениям. Очевидно, мы должны сделать (b+1-a) шагов вниз, и a шагов по диагонали, вопрос только в очередности этих шагов. Таким образом, ответ:  `(b+1)! / a! / (b-a+1)!`

Пренебрегая первый множителем в формуле Стирлинга, получим:
`O((b+1)! / a! / (b-a+1)!) = O( (b/(b-a+1))^(b-a+1) * (b/a)^a )`

Худшим a для заданного b, очевидно, является  a=b/2. Оставляя зависимость от одного параметра b, получим `O(2^b)`, однако, так предоставлять не стоит, поскольку в случае если пользователя интересует рост сложность, "в заданном направлении" на плоскости a-b, эта формула может существенно завысить сложность. Если нужно избавиться от знаменателей, я бы советовал использовать: `O( min( (b-a)^a, a^(b-a), 2^b ) )`, по крайней, мере она правильно описывает окрестности границ: a<<b, (b-a)<<b .

Comment: ... т.е. после некоторых преобразований в худшем случае a ~ b/2, O(2^n)...

Comment: Вы срезали угол, оценив значение функции вместо её сложности. Сложность немного больше значения из-за того что функция иногда возвращает нули. Но на уровне вопроса это простительно. От меня плюсик.

Answer (score 1):

<del>В худшем случае когда `a = b`</del> сложность алгоритма будет `O(2^max(a,b))`, так как каждый вызов функции делает два рекурсивных вызова, пока один из аргументов не достигнет нуля.

Comment: Нет. Левую часть `no_zeroes(a, b - 1)` более сложно посчитать из-за `if (a > b + 1) {        return 0;    }`

Comment: Кстати, `a==b` далеко не худший случай... Вот как выглядит график — https://i121.fastpic.org/big/2023/0428/12/7cfa3fcc50b4a5efc9175c8a166ea312.jpg

Comment: @Harry Можете навести пример?

Comment: Да легко. Например, для 5,8 — 363 вызова, а для 8,8 — 73.

Comment: А вот график логарифма. https://i121.fastpic.org/big/2023/0428/4d/445014ed7d85ac8f4c884683aa6fba4d.jpg

Comment: @Harry Как определить сложность в таком случае? она явно зависит от max(a,b)

Comment: Так я и не претендую :) Сделал бы — дал бы ответ, а я ограничиваюсь комментариями... Но есть у меня подозрение, что наихудший случай при `a == b/2`...